# WCF - Moving MVC Framework from WinForms to an SOA for Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I would like to move my MVC pattern (BLL and DAL - POCOs) from a WinForms environment to a Silverlight environment.  As I begin this transition, do I have to do anything extra to my POCOs for WCF consumption, i.e. move them down the wire, e.g. serilize them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The classes must be decorated with [DataContract], and the properties with [DataMember]. WCF uses an "opt-in" system, where you must say which parts of your classes need to be serialized.